# Handlebar.js and Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, handlebars.js

I'm having an issue which I can't debug too easily. I've got this application which is rendering a specific type of file from Gists. It works well in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari and IE it doesn't render content passed in via handlebars.js - I know the template is being read correctly and inserted on the page (all those sections in the page are defined using handlebars), but the content is not there. Do you have any ideas? I searched around but didn't see any real issues with handlebars and Safari.

http://www.antarctic-design.co.uk/isafiles/isaviewer-demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in line 94 ISATabViewer.js:

```
if (divs[div].innerHTML) {}
```

replace

```
if (divs[div].textContent) {}
```

Safari returns `undefined`, Chrome returns content. Nothing in common with handlebars

Comment: Ah! Did not pick up on that. Thanks!